# как собрать html js в один компонент

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js

есть задача собрать html js файл в один компонент чтобы можно было переиспользовать в реакте и vue, не подскажите с помощью чего можно реализовать данную задачу?

в html подключается еще js библиотека Sipml.js

заранее спасибо!

Comment: `с помощью чего можно реализовать данную задачу?` — а с помощью текстового редактора не выходит скопировать/вставить строчки из одного файла в другой?